# Error finding the resource dictionary [Fluent.Ribbon]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, fluent-ribbon

I have added fluent.dll as reference. After that add a folder on my project called "Themes" and pasted the all theme folder on "Themes" directory. On my application.xaml i have added the below code i.e

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Attach Default Fluent Control's Theme-->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;  Component/Themes/Office2013/Generic.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But when run it show a error that

> an error occurred while finding the resource dictionary

I am using Vs2013 .net ver4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your spacing is wrong

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;  Component/Themes/Office2013/Generic.xaml" />
```

should be

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Office2013/Generic.xaml" />
```